# VBA excel Can not Login to Website via Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this code for a while and It works just fine on my computer, but when I share the file with others some computers can not Login into Website. Any one know the solution to this issue. All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Set Mybrowser = New InternetExplorer
Mybrowser.Visible = True
Mybrowser.navigate "/index.php?r=site/index"
    
''LOGIN USER AND PASSOWRD
''************************************
Set HTMLdoc = Mybrowser.document
HTMLdoc.forms("yw0").elements("Login").Value = usr
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
HTMLdoc.forms("yw0").elements("psw").Value = psw

''CLICK SUBMIT LOGIN
''************************************
Set HTMLbtnS = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
    
For Each HTMLbtn In HTMLbtnS
    ''Debug.Print HTMLbtn.getAttribute("type")
    If HTMLbtn.getAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
        HTMLbtn.Click
    End If
Next HTMLbtn
```

below is the References VBA :

[image]

I can not Login with this code again.

Comment: Rather than `application.wait` use `Mybrowser.Busy Or Mybrowser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE`  to check that the browser is not doing anything, the other computer may take longer than 3 seconds.  Also, when loading the form.  What is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: No error message, But It cannot login. I have been using this code for a while and It works just fine on my computer. is it Binding Problem?

Comment: are the values being entered in the right places?  Have you stepped through the code on the other computers?

Comment: Yes , the values being entered in the right places. But no error appears. My User n Password are correct. but it cannot Login. Sometimes it works. Is it problem because early or lately Binding?